# How can I make a timer start & work only when onFocus is true?

Tags: javascript, timer, onfocus

I have this timer (see Code below). How can I make sure that the countdown starts AND keeps counting down *only if* the browser window is `onFocus`?

(I want it to pause if the user opens another window, for example.)

```
//Countdown

function timerCountdown()
{
    x=100;
    document.getElementById('timer1').value=x;
    x=x-1;
    t=setTimeout("timerCountdown()",1000);

    if (c<-1)
    {
        document.getElementById('timer1').value='Go';
        clearTimeout(t);

    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to detect if a browser window is not currently active?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active)

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onblur = function() {
  // Stop counting
}

window.onfocus = function() {
  // Start counting
}
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your response.

I actually used the original code but added the onblur and onfocus inthe the body tag. See below

Comment: Thanks for your response.

I kind of found a way to do that but it's still causing me a little problem:

I created a function

function stopCounter(){
clearTimeout(t);
x=x+1
}
Then, when I change the body tag to that:

<body onFocus='timerCountdown()' onBlur='stopCounter()'>
It does what I want but it doesn't start on it own. It waits for me to Blur then reFocus on the current page.

And if I try this:

<body onLoad='timerCountdown()' onFocus='timerCountdown()' onBlur='stopCounter()'>


The timer starts going very fast. And it goes even faster when I refresh the page.

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: check state before start/stop counting. `clearTimeout()` when it is the time.